# Finding optimum point that minimizes maximum distance

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

Does anyone know how I should approach this algorithm? It needs to have $O(n^3)$ complexity and I can only come up with an algorithm that has $O(n^4)$ complexity (of doing a n^2 min path from each vertex to $n-1$ other vertexes, and since I need to do this n times, it will be $n^4$ or so I think...

> *Input*: Array $A[1...n][1...n]$ such that $A[i][j]$ gives length of edge(distance) between two points or $-1$ if there isn't and edge.
>
> *Output*: a vertex $v$, such that distances(total lengths) to all other vertexes are minimized.

Can someone explain in pseudocode or in words how to do this?

Comment: compute all pair shortest path distances, and update the distance matrix. This operation takes $O(n^3)$ using Floyd Warshall algorithm. Now with the updated distance matrix, sum the values along each column (row) and then choose the index with the least sum.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Answer (score 3):

you can use Floyd Warshall algorithm to find distance of every pair and then just use a simple for to find the sum of distance of any of vertices  and print the minimum of them